# How to tell if a header file was visited in Mbed

Tags: c++, c, header-files, mbed

I'm using Mbed to write some code for the KL46Z and I'm having trouble referencing some variables found in the lower level header files.  Since all the compilation is done on their servers I'm not able to pass any compiler options.  I'm curious how I would be able to tell which header files in the Mbed library are being referenced?

Comment: What OS are you building on? On UN*X, you can use `strace make 2>&1 | grep <your-header-file-name>`

Comment: I'm using the mbed online development platform so that information is hidden and there is no way to pass any compiler options
https://mbed.org/